# get caller module code in perl

Tags: perl

How could I get actual code from the caller module in perl?

**some_module.pm**

```
package some_module;

use my_module;

CODE
CODE
```

**my_module.pm**

```
package my_module;

sub import {

  my $package = caller;

  my $code = actual perl code of some_module.pm;

}
```

Is this possible, or would I have to use an `open` function? I would think source filters do something similar.

Comment: Why do you want this?!

Comment: I'm writing a mod that modifies a module code and prints the source differently

Comment: That doesn't really answer anything. Why would you want to pretty print a module obtained by `caller`?

Comment: If I put "use mymod" in any module, I want mymod to copy the code and modify it in a certain way (whether it is for some kind of future filter, language translation, whatever), and save it to a new file. This can be useful when I'm working on a module and changing its contents often.

Comment: @Jonathan Surely it would be better to implement that as an external tool: `$ yourtool somescript.pl`. Anyway, I have the feeling that we actually have an X-Y-Problem here: You asked about discovering the filename of a calling module, but actually want to automatically apply sourcecode transformations. If you tell us *what kind* of transformations (e.g. metaprogramming, RCS keyword substitution, pretty printing with `perltidy`), then we might be able to point to an actual solution, instead of giving confusing answers.

Comment: @amon I want to get the latest code, not filename, of a module every time it is run and save a modified version. That way each time the module is updated, I can be confident my modified version is up to date. This can be useful in many ways, including comparing different versions of modules as they are being developed. First time anyone has ever asked me Why. My brain things more along the lines of can it be done, then should it be done.

Comment: “*comparing different versions of modules*” – this is what version control like Git or SVN is good for. If you want to create a derivative resource from your code, you could use a build system like `make`, commit hooks for your version control solution, or various Perl-specific tools. Doing all the work every time your program is run is wasteful – do it only if something changed.

Comment: @amon I'm sure there could be better ways, but I found my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a CPAN module called [B::Hooks::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/B%3a%3aHooks%3a%3aParser) that allows you to not just see, but *alter* the line where you were called. (That is, not alter it on disk, but alter what Perl sees while it's parsing the line.) Though you cannot see or alter the part of the line which has already been compiled. This only works at compile time of course, and because the Perl parser reads and tokenizes one line at a time, it is limited to looking at a single line.

If you need to see the entire file that's called you, you can use:

```
open my $caller_fh, '<', (caller)[1]
    or die("Cannot open caller: $!");
```

However `(caller)[1]` might not always return a real filename - for example, if you are called from a one-liner, it will be "-e", or from a stringy eval will be something like "(eval 23)".

Comment: What general method does this mod use to modify the rest of the code that has not been compiled yet? I can't figure how this is possible. How would you modify the code that is loaded into memory to be compiled?

Comment: @Jonathan The parser hooks allow you to register a callback for a new keyword, e.g. `method` or `try`. Now when perl finds that keyword while parsing the source, it hands off control to the callback. The CB can now either alter the text right after the keyword and let perl resume parsing, or can directly return executable Opcodes. Either way, the keyword can't be changed so you will also have a subroutine of the same name that implements the runtime behavior. See `TryCatch`, `Function::Parameters` and `Moops` for good examples of syntax extensions.

Comment: B::Hooks::Parser pre-dates the keyword API. The keyword API is used by Function::Parameters and Moops, but not TryCatch. TryCatch uses Devel::Declare. B::Hooks::Parser and Devel::Declare both use XS to call some of the Perl's parsers's internal functions. It's scary stuff. :-)

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this! I see that these functions load C modules. I thought the only advantage of loading C modules was speed. The perl compiler is already compiled from C, so how can these function's access perl's core?

Comment: Modules written using C have access to Perl's internals because they link against the Perl headers. (Without doing so they couldn't manipulate Perl variables, call callbacks, etc.) Speed is one advantage of writing code in C, but there are others: access to Perl's internals, more powerful (though vastly more manual) memory management, and the ability to link against other libraries written in or C/C++ (for example, XML::LibXML uses C to talk to the GNOME libxml2 library).